# Xamarin Forms Drag Image between Views

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have an application in Xamarin Forms, and I need that the user can choose one image from below and drag anywhere he wants to in the top view, the idea is: The below view with the images are the home rooms, and the top view is the Houseplant, the user can create his houseplant by dragging and rotating the images, and then finally save the top view as a jpg or png image.

I've searched here and 2 3 pages of google about drag and etc, but I haven't found anything that could help me with that, I tried pan gesture, tap gesture, but no success =[

Sorry if it is duplicated or something, this is my first post, and I really couldn't find anything.

How can I get this working in Xamarin.Forms or at least with custom renderers and etc?

Thank you guys.

[Sample image of what I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrCRI.png)

Comment: Well i have a doubt this images can they be moved around anywhere in the upper screen portion

Comment: @G.hakim, Yes I think that too... =[, maybe if I have a main view, and then 2 children (bottom and top), and then when the user tap the image in the bottom view, I can detach and put in the main view, I dunno =[, I think at the moment I can't do that

Comment: You wont find a ready made thing for this but it can surely be done with no issues if you have time.

Answer (score 0):

For your image in XAML:

```
<Image Source="plant.png" x:Name="image"/>
```

You can actually use pan gesture recognizers to drag and drop images in C#:

Define variables:

```
double x; // totalX for the pan gesture
double y; // totalY for the pan gesture
```

Initialize pan gesture and add it to the image:

```
PanGestureRecognizer panGesture = new PanGestureRecognizer();
panGesture.PanUpdated += PanUpdated;
image.GestureRecognizers.Add(panGesture);
```

The event handler for the gesture:

```
void PanUpdated(object sender, PanUpdatedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.StatusType.Equals(GestureStatus.Running)) {
        x = args.TotalX;
        y = args.TotalY;

        image.TranslateTo(x, y, 1);
    }
    else if (args.StatusType.Equals(GestureStatus.Completed)) {
        // set the layout bounds of the image to the new position
        // method varies depending on what type of layout you are using for the image

        // eg. assume the image is in an absolute layout
        // where the layout height is the screen height
        // and the layout width is the screen width

        Task.Run(() => {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => // run UI task on main thread
            {
                await Task.Delay(50); // avoid flickering

                var screenWidth = Application.Current.MainPage.Width;
                var screenHeight = Application.Current.MainPage.Height;

                var b = image.Bounds;
                var newBounds = new Rectangle(b.X + x, b.Y + y, b.Width, b.Height);

                var newAbsoluteBound =
                    new Rectangle(newBounds.X / (screenWidth - newBounds.Width),
                                  newBounds.Y / (screenHeight - newBounds.Height),
                                  newBounds.Width / screenWidth,
                                  newBounds.Height / screenHeight);

                // set new absolute bounds so a new TranslateTo can be applied

                AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(image, newAbsoluteBound);
                await image.TranslateTo(0, 0, 0);
            });
        });              
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer, I'll try that, but what about the Views? I mean, my bottom view where the user will select the image will probably be a Grid/Scrollview, and the top view will be a Absolute/Stack, do I need to detach the image from the grid/scrollview when the user tap?

Comment: You probably have to detach and add it to the new view when you drop the image

Comment: Yes... I'll try that and let you guys know, thank you for the attention, I think it'll be difficult at the moment in Xamarin

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your page or Image is not in a scrollView. 
If ScrollView is enabled for both orientations, Pan-Gesture wont work.
.
.